# How to use multi where condition with elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm using laravel + elasticsearch.
I have an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "product_title",
        "stocks": [
            {
                "country": "EN",
                "stock": 0
            },
            {
                "country": "IN",
                "stock": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "product_title_2",
        "stocks": [
            {
                "country": "EN",
                "stock": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "IN",
                "stock": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want to find all objects has `country` equal `EN` and `stock` is greater than `1`.

---

**updated**

my query:

```
{
    "index": "products",
    "body": {
        "size": 15,
        "from": 1,
        "sort": [
            {
                "stock": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "**",
                            "type": "best_fields",
                            "fields": [
                                "erp_id",
                                "title_en^2",
                                "translations.title^2",
                                "erp.title_en",
                                "erp.title",
                                "erp.options.title",
                                "erp.options.title_en"
                            ],
                            "analyze_wildcard": true,
                            "allow_leading_wildcard": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "is_active": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "shops.shop_id": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "max_price": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "erp.price_lists.currency.abbr": "tmn"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "result": {
                        "max": {
                            "field": "erp.price_lists.pivot.price_tt"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "min_price": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "erp.price_lists.currency.abbr": "tmn"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "result": {
                        "min": {
                            "field": "erp.price_lists.pivot.price_tt"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking the expression to search this in Elastcsearch or in PHP?

Comment: @enriqueojedalara updated my question. added my query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) along with [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html) to get the object satisfying the requirements

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "stocks": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title": "product_title_2",
  "stocks": [
    {
      "country": "EN",
      "stock": 1
    },
    {
      "country": "IN",
      "stock": 0
    }
  ]
}
{
  "title": "product_title",
  "stocks": [
    {
      "country": "EN",
      "stock": 0
    },
    {
      "country": "IN",
      "stock": 1
    }
  ]
}
{
  "title": "product_title_3",
  "stocks": [
    {
      "country": "EN",
      "stock": 2
    },
    {
      "country": "IN",
      "stock": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "stocks",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "stocks.country": "EN"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "stocks.stock": {
                  "gt": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "67294405",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "product_title_3",
      "stocks": [
        {
          "country": "EN",
          "stock": 2
        },
        {
          "country": "IN",
          "stock": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "inner_hits": {
      "stocks": {
        "hits": {
          "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
          },
          "max_score": 0.0,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "67294405",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_id": "3",
              "_nested": {
                "field": "stocks",
                "offset": 0
              },
              "_score": 0.0,
              "_source": {
                "country": "EN",
                "stock": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Consider using `bool/filter` instead of `bool/must` for exact matches

Comment: Also there's no `inner_hits` section in your query

Comment: The difference between `must` and `filter` is that `filter` does not affect the score, while `must` does so it's not necessarily about exact matches. In this case you might (or might not) want items that match both to score higher than items that match one of the two conditions. Since that's unclear from the question I think `must` and `filter` would be equally valid

Comment: @ESCoder updated my question. added my query.